# server and client side validation differences adding extra span

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I have validation which is both on server side and client side 
When the validation is added on the server side i get a different structure to when i do it on the client side

Client

```
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Location" class="text-danger field-validation-error"><span for="Location" class="">The Location field is required.</span></span>
```

Server side

```
<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Location" class="field-validation-error text-danger">Broken</span>
```

the problem is

```
<span for="Location" class="">
```

Is their a way to make the server side validation add the extra span?
Or Is their a way to make the client side validation remove the extra span?

Any help appreciated :)

Model

```
    public class LocationModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LocationView(LocationModel lm)
{

    ModelState.AddModelError("Location", "Broken");

    return View();
}
```

View

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.LocationModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>LocationModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Surely this is something someone has come across before :(

Comment: Why is this a problem? Its the default behavior. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is a problem.

But here is the code generating the extra span. Code is in jquery.validate.js.

```
showLabel: function( element, message ) {

        ...

        } else {
            // create error element
            error = $( "<" + this.settings.errorElement + ">" )
                .attr( "id", elementID + "-error" )
                .addClass( this.settings.errorClass )
                .html( message || "" );

        ...
    },
```

The default value for errorElement is *label*, but jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js changes that to *span*. 
There are several ways you can change this behavior.

But here is one, change jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js

from:

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element

    ...

    if (replace) {
        container.empty();
        error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);
    }

    ...

}
```

To:

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element

    ...

    if (replace) {
        container.empty().html(error.html());
    }

    ...

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! thank you for this answer- in response to why - i believe having two  different syntax's to display errors is a little inconsistent. surely the way without the additional span is specific enough